# Tensorflow Bazel Build error:no such package

Tags: windows, tensorflow, bazel

I was trying to build tensorflow 1.13.1 from source but failed,the error occurred as below:

```
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so': error loading package 'tensorflow': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1556
                _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1395, in _create_local_cuda_repository
                find_cc(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 239, in find_cc
                _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 156, in _get_msvc_compiler
                find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path, "cl.exe").replace("\\", "/")
type 'NoneType' has no method replace(string, string)
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1556
                _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1395, in _create_local_cuda_repository
                find_cc(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 239, in find_cc
                _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/d/tensorflow-1.13.1/source/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 156, in _get_msvc_compiler
                find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path, "cl.exe").replace("\\", "/")
type 'NoneType' has no method replace(string, string)
```

It seems Bazel doesn't recognize @local_config_cuda\\cuda as a package.
Why? And what shall I do?

Comment: It looks like it's having trouble trying to find `cl.exe` in your MSVC path.

Comment: That's right.I reinstall Visual Studio with C++ and build tensorflow succesful.